# How to access class field

Tags: c#

I am learning c# language and still at the very basics of understanding scope of variables. I am not sure how I can access the filed in class C1 in class C2

I have tried using the public keyword when declaring int i

```
using System;

namespace MyClass
{
    class C1
    {
        int i = 5;
    }
    class C2
    {
        int j = i;
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value is {i}");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of "Value is 5" but the following error shows up

```
test.cs(11,10): error CS0103: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context
test.cs(14,33): error CS0103: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context
test.cs(7,6): warning CS0414: The field 'C1.i' is assigned but its value is never used
```

Comment: A class is just a template. You'll have to create an instance for it to be able to access fields, such as `i`. Don't forget to make them public as well, as the default accessor is private. I would recommend a good C# tutorial.

Comment: Make it public and make it a property.  Perhaps give it a meaningful name too.

Comment: FYI: Note that what you have in your code are "**instance fields**", not "class fields". There is something like "class fields" (or rather "class variables"), which in .NET are called "static fields" (static fields are declared by using the `static` keyword in the field declaration).

Comment: I got it to work using static keyword. Thanks @elgonzo. However, I am still not able to use the instance field

Comment: @elgonzo this works `using System;

namespace MyClass
{
    class C1
    {
        public static int i = 5;
    }
    class C2
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value is {C1.i}");
        }
    }
}` if I remove `static` in C1 and change C2 to `C1 c1Obj = new C1();
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value is {c1Obj.i}");` gives me error `test.cs(14,43): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'C2.c1Obj'` Can you explain why.

Comment: Look carefully at the error message. What **precisely** is the error about? What piece of your code does the compiler **exactly** have an issue with?

Answer (score -1):

C1 c1instance=new C1();
int j = C1.i;

Oh and change int i = 5; to public int i = 5;

It's not perfect, but that should get you started

Comment: This is not "best practices, just an answer to your question, I'd personally use a public property for "i" (and never use single letters for a variable)

Comment: I tried the code as suggested `using System;

namespace MyClass
{
    class C1
    {
        public int i = 5;
    }
    class C2
    {
        C1 c1instance = new C1();
        int j = c1instance.i;
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value is {j}");
        }
    }
}` but I get the following error `test.cs(12,17): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
property 'C2.c1instance'
test.cs(15,43): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or p
roperty 'C2.j'`